# Align environment inside TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, align

I'm new to TikZ, and I'm trying to use the `align` enviroment to align some text then draw something on it using some TikZ lines.

But the problem that pdfLaTeX is generating an error whenever I try to put the `alignment` enviroment inside a TikZ picture.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{align}
    \notag &a_1,\ &b_1,\ &c_1,\ &d_1,\ &e_1\ \mbox{etc.}\\
    \notag &a_2,\ &b_2,\ &c_2,\ &d_2,\ &e_2\ \mbox{etc.}
\end{align} 

%% draw some stuff using tikz on the the aligned text.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

but I'm always getting this error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.358 \end{align}
```

P.S. If I put the `align` outside the TikZ enviroment, everything works normally.

Comment: Perhaps your example is too minimal.  Do you want to annotate the aligned elements?  Because that can be done totally inside a tikzpicture with a matrix of nodes.  Feel free to expand on what you intend with "draw some stuff using tikz on the aligned text".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not just a problem with `align` but with almost any other non-`tikz` construction.  You need to put `tikz` in to a situation where it will be expecting ordinary LaTeX commands.  One of these is the label for a node.  Now to protect things further from `tikz`'s parsing, you can include the material in a `minipage` as below.  Similar issues would be seen with e.g. the non-AMS `displaymath`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
    \notag &a_1,\ &b_1,\ &c_1,\ &d_1,\ &e_1\ \mbox{etc.}\\
    \notag &a_2,\ &b_2,\ &c_2,\ &d_2,\ &e_2\ \mbox{etc.}
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}
};
%% draw some stuff using tikz on the the aligned text.
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside `tikzpicture` you should speak `tikz` language. This can be put indise a `node` and a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}%adjust width here
\begin{align}
    \notag &a_1,\ &b_1,\ &c_1,\ &d_1,\ &e_1\ \mbox{etc.}\\
    \notag &a_2,\ &b_2,\ &c_2,\ &d_2,\ &e_2\ \mbox{etc.}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
};
%% draw some stuff using tikz on the the aligned text.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]